# I can't return a value

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, return

I'm trying to write a function that will translate the input into so-called "cow Latin." I want to return the values from the `if` statement but whenever I do I get a syntax error. I can print the value but I want to avoid the function returning `None` as well.

```
def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    vowels = tuple('aeiou1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+|\\][}{?/.\',><`~"')
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence_list = sentence.split()
    for i in range(len(sentence_list)):
        cow_word = sentence_list[i][:]
        if cow_word.startswith(vowels):
            print('{0}moo'.format(cow_word), end=' ')
        else:
            cow_word = sentence_list[i][1:] + sentence_list[i][:1]
            print('{0}oo'.format(cow_word), end=' ')

cow_latin = cow_latinify_sentence("the quick red fox")
print(cow_latin)
```

In short, how can I get the function to `return` instead of `print`?

Comment: Use a `return` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    vowels = tuple('aeiou1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+|\\][}{?/.\',><`~"')
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence_list = sentence.split()
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(sentence_list)):
        cow_word = sentence_list[i][:]
        if cow_word.startswith(vowels):
            result += ('{0}moo'.format(cow_word) + ' ')
        else:
            result += '{0}oo'.format(sentence_list[i][1:] + sentence_list[i][:1]) + ' '
    return result.strip()
```

---

```
>>> cow_latinify_sentence('hello there i am a fish')
'ellohoo heretoo imoo ammoo amoo ishfoo'
```

Comment: Thank you oh so very much! I'm new to python as you can probably tell and spent a lot of time trying to get it to return. That is so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace the two instances of

```
print('{0}moo'.format(cow_word), end=' ')
```

with

```
return '{0}moo'.format(cow_word)+' '
```

You have to get rid of `end=`; you don't have to replace the newline that would otherwise follow the output of `print`, but if you want a space at the end of the returned string you still have to append it yourself.

Comment: When I do that I only seem to get the first letter from the sentence back. Thanks a lot for your quick response! I really appreciate it.

Comment: The `print` statements occur within a loop, so `return`ing immediately won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list to accumulate your results.

```
result = []
```

your two print statements in your function would need changed to result.append(XXXX). Then when you have processed the entire sentence you can

```
return (result)
```

or, to re-form it into a sentence:

```
return " ".join(result) + '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cow_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    vowels = tuple('aeiou1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+|\\][}{?/.\',><`~"')
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence_list = sentence.split()
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(sentence_list)):
        cow_word = sentence_list[i][:]
        if cow_word.startswith(vowels):
            result += '{0}moo'.format(cow_word) + ' '
        else:
            result += '{0}oo'.format(sentence_list[i][1:] + sentence_list[i][:1]) + ' '
    return result.strip()
```